# Netsuite Advanced PDF Item Sorting

Tags: pdf, netsuite, bin, picklist, bfo

I created a Picklist using Advanced PDF in NetSuite. I want the items to be sorted out based on the BIN Number. Is there a way to sort the items based on the BIN number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can sort by adding the `?sort_by()` parameter to the `#list` declaration.  For example, change this:

```
<#list record.item as item>
```

to this:

```
<#list record.item?sort_by("inventorydetail") as item>
```

in order to sort by `inventorydetail` - which typically contains bin numbers.  To sort by a different field, you can just change the field id inside the parentheses.

Be aware, however, that when you do this the order of the items on the pick ticket will no longer align with the order on the item fulfillment when you go to fulfill the order in the NetSuite UI.  This may make fulfilling more difficult and error prone, as you have to look for each item individually and cross-reference instead of just working down the list - but it may work for you.

There is also an *Enhancement Request* to add the ability to sort the item sublist by any field currently with NetSuite, which would overcome both of these issues.  It's Enhancement # - *3935*, so send in a support request to get your account added to the list of people wanting this feature if you can see value in it.

Comment: Thanks...I already got the answer.